# MIx environment variables from kubernetes deployment and docker image

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables

I am trying to pass an environment variable in my deployment that should define a prefix based on a version number:

```
env:
  - name: INDEX_PREFIX
    value: myapp-$(VERSION)
```

`$(VERSION)` is not defined in my deployment but is set in the docker image used by the pod.
I tried to use both `$()` and `${}` but `VERSION` is not interpolated in the environment of my pod. In my pod shell doing `export TEST=myapp-${VERSION}` does work though.

Is there any way to achieve what I am looking for? ie setting an environment variable in my deployment that reference an environment variable set in the docker image?

Answer (score 3):

`VERSION` is an environment variable of the docker image. So you can assign it a value either inside the container or by passing

```
env: 
   - name : VERSION
     value : YOUR-VALUE
```

In your case, `VERSION` is either set by a script inside the docker container or in the Dockerfile.

You can do :

1. In the Dockerfile, adding `ENV INDEX_PREFIX myapp-${VERSION}`
2. Adding a script to your entrypoint as
   `export  INDEX_PREFIX=myapp-${VERSION}`

In case you can't modify Dockerfile, you can try to :

- Get the image entrypoint file from the docker image (ie: /IMAGE-entrypoint.sh) and the image args(ie: IMAGE-ARGS). you can use `docker inspect IMAGE`.
- Override the container command and args in the pod spec using a script.

```
   command:
           - '/bin/sh'
   args:
           - '-c'
           - |
             set -e
             set -x
             export INDEX_PREFIX=myapp-${VERSION} 
             IMAGE-entrypoint.sh IMAGE-ARGS
```

k8s documentation : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/
Hope it could help you.

Comment: What do you mean by add a script to your entrypoint? Execute this as a command in the container spec? As far as I could test it doesn't work.

Comment: @wassim-trifi Currently changing the image is not an option.

Comment: @ITChap Oh I see. These solutions are possibles only if you change the image build through the Dockerfile. In this case try to override the container _Command_ and _Args_ fields.